# 1and1 Domain and Heroku - Too many Redirects

Tags: domains, dns, heroku, 1and1

I have an App hosted on Heroku, Domain and DNS Target is `<appname>.herokuapp.com`, as usual.

My 1and1 Domain `<domain>.net` is set up to HTTP-redirect to `www.<domain>.net`.
I added the `www` subdomain which has the CNAME Alias `<appname>.herokuapp.com`.

This should work, at least i've read about this "workaround" in several threads on Stackoverflow / Webmasters.

However, accessing either `<domain>.net` *or* `www.<domain>.net` leads to a "Too many Redirects" error.

There are no .htaccess files on the entire associated 1and1 webspace if that matters. The Heroku app is written in Node.js and works fine when accessed via the Heroku Domain. How can i resolve this?

**Edit:**

These are the DNS Settings:

## Root - `<domain>.net`

Nameserver: 1&1 Nameserver (Default)
A/AAAA Entry (Ip address): 1&1 IP-Address (Default)

## Subdomain - `www.<domain>.net`

DNS Settings: CNAME - Alias: `<appname>.herokuapp.com`

Comment: Can you show us the DNS settings for <domain>.net and www.<domain>.net?  Copy and paste.

Comment: @Steve Added them

Answer (score 2):

The **< appname >.herokuapp.com** target is doing virtualhosting (hosting multiple domains on one IP) and your space is configured to serve requests for **< appname >.herokuapp.com** but since you made a CNAME of **www.< domain >.net** pointing to it, the target is getting a request for **www.< domain >.net** and unless the target is specifically configured to do something for that hostname, it will not work as expected.

Comment: handle www.domain.net yourself (why not the same space as domain.net) and make both redirect to appname.herokuapp.com.If your aim is to have your own url visible in the addressbar instead of the herokuapp one, then, unless you can get them to handle your virtualhostname, I see no solution but have the herokuapp page it in a (fullpage) frame, which I don't find very clean.